# How to get handle WKInterfaceTimer Count event?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I want to be a countdown using the WkInterfaceTimer.
As of NSTiemer, I want to get an event that occurs when the countdown is.

The WkInterfaceTimer does not have such a Delegate, how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [WKInterfaceTimer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacetimer) explains it well:

> A WKInterfaceTimer object is a special type of **label** that displays a countdown or count-up timer. 
>   ...
>   To know when the timer reaches 0, **configure an NSTimer object** with the same target date you used to set up the timer.

So basically, use an NSTimer on the watch in the same way as you would in an iOS app, and just use the WKInterfaceTimer as a way of showing a countdown on the watch screen.

Comment: Thank you very much. understood.